# Tricky situation on Bean and Reflection

Tags: java, reflection, javabeans, pojo

I want to read a flat file with contents like "Deepak,25,Singhal" and then populate the POJO dynamically. I got the method object using reflection. I also created an instance using newInstance().

Problem I am stuck is method.invoke( obj, Object ..) ..Now how do I determine the Type of argument to be passed ! From Method object how do I know that argument to be passed is int; so that I could convert String 25 to corresponding type so that method.invoke could be invoked !

Comment: [Method#getParameterTypes](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Method.html#getParameterTypes())

Comment: yes I tried getParameterType which is giving me Type .. But how to proceed further ! I want to dynamically convert the String to this Type.

Comment: http://balusc.blogspot.it/2007/08/generic-object-converter.html

Comment: In the usage you are hardcoding it to Integer.class or String.class etc but what we have is value like int,float, java.lang.String which is returned by getParameterTypes(). And also, you have hardcoded many conversions methods ! Isnt there a generic way to do conversion in which I would say that convert String 25 to int or to float

Comment: I did nothing, it's not my blog ;) Anyway, I don't know how you can do it differently

Answer (score -1):

Use a java class with the help of Regular expression to identify Strings and number sand convert to respective type generically